# Open free encrypted adt table using Arc

Tags: ads, advantage-database-server

Is there a way to open an encrypted free Advantage table using Arc?

The table in question is an auto-generated .bak as a restructure result of a DD bound table.  I'd like to open that .bak table using ARC but it is failing with error 5004. I suspect the problem is that it is encrypted.  Even after freeing the table using Arc, trying to add the table to a DD using sp_AddTableToDatabase() stored procedure fails with error 5130.  Perhaps the table is associated to the very same DD where the restructured table is.

It begs the question; how can I open an encrypted .adt.bak table?

I tried using SQL inside ARC after renaming the table from paytemp.adt.bak to paytemp.adt.

EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_addTableToDatabase( 'paytemp', 'paytemp.adt', 3, 1, NULL, NULL );

EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_DecryptTable( 'paytemp.adt' );

Any ideas?

Comment: `sp_DecryptTable` requires two parameters (the table name and the password) for a free table. Youve only specified the table name.

Comment: @Ken --Yes, I'm sending the password as 2nd parameter. But then I get error #5132: "...paytemp is not a table in the data dictionary".  I'm guessing the table is not being freed using ARC ->Tools ->Free table because it is encrypted.

Comment: ...also, if I try to add the table to an existing DD, I get error 5130. "..the table is not a free table.  It is already associated with a data dictionary".

Comment: I suspect that Advantage is treating the table exactly as it is designed to do to prevent improper access to encrypted data, and that your efforts aren't going to get anywhere. (And that's actually a good thing, because it means your data is pretty secure.)

Comment: Ken is right: A table encrypted inside a DD can not be decrypted without a connection to that DD. So you're probably out of luck if you don't have access to the DD anyomre.

Comment: The reason is that table encryption for free tables works differently than encryption for DD tables by design.

Comment: @Jens; Yes, exactly;  table encryption for free tables works differently than for dd bound tables.  It makes sense;  now **remember** this table is the .bak table that results from a re-structure.  After a re-structure the newly re-structured table is automatically bounded to the DD, the original table is removed from the DD and renamed with .bak extension.  You can't free it because it is encrypted and you can't added to its original DD because it is bound already to it, although it has been removed from the DD.   What good is a .bak table that can't accessed at all? Get it?

Comment: @ Ken + Jens;  Keep in mind the way Advantage knows this table is bound to a DD is because of metadata on the table.  When a table is restructured, I suspect, Advantage renames the table with .bak extension and removes it from the DD in order to accommodate the newly re-structured table on the DD but does **not** remove metadata on the table that indicates that table is bound to a dd.    If the table wasn't part of an encrypted DD, you could simply free it.  But this is not the case here.  I'm sure there is a way.  I'm hoping someone knows.  Help?

Comment: The only way I see is to somehow add it back to the original DD and then access it throught that.

Comment: Maybe you should try to contact Joachim Dürr, he is a former Extended Systems employee and he is still doing consulting work for ADS: https://www.jd-engineering.de/impressum/kontakt/

Comment: Another option is to ask on SVP Q&A: https://answers.sap.com/tags/67838200100800005437

Comment: Thank you, Jens.  I will try that.

Comment: You can run the freeadt.exe utility in the arc install directory to see if there is any error - you will need the table encryption password from DD. Once its freed, you should be able open it.

Comment: Thank you @Alex W.  It is always good to hear from you.  I'd love to know what are you doing now days.  Write me a note.  reinaldo.crespo@gmail.com

Comment: Just for future reference, I think I solved this problem by editing the table header using a hex editor to remove the DD reference.  That frees the table that can now be opened as a free table providing encryption password.